# Versioning related media types individually or in lockstep in a RESTful API

Tags: rest, media-type

I'm developing a REST API around an ecommerce site and one of my resources is an Order which contains information like went it was made, the ID, the status, when it will be shipped, etc.

I have defined a media type for my Order resource like so:

```
application/vnd.myapp.order.v1+json
```

I also have defined another resource which is the status of an order, like so:

```
application/vnd.myapp.order-status.v1+json
```

My question is around the versioning of these media types. Seeing as they're related, would it make sense to version them in lockstep? For example, if the representation of the order resource changes and I create a `application/vnd.myapp.order.v2+json`, would it wise to also bump the version of the order-status media type to v2 as well? I'm also wondering if any there is a RESTful option with regards to the guidelines. I did have a look around online and couldn't really find anything talking about the best practice here, so any advice/opinions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think mixing version and media type is a good idea.

In my opinion, you should separate it according to 'separate concerns principle' and 'single responsibility'.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle

Many teams use header/url for versioning:
For example:
/api/v1/
/api/v2/
header {version:'v1'}
header {version:'v2'}

Then we can easily map the request with our need:

```
@RequestMapping(value="api/v1/books", consumes="application/json")
@RequestMapping(value="api/v2/books", consumes="application/json")
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value="api/books",headers="version=v1", consumes="application/json")
@RequestMapping(value="api/books",headers="version=v2", consumes="application/json")
```

Comment: Can you expand on why it isn't a good idea? "Not being a good separation of concerns" in this context is a bit vague and not concrete.

Comment: we use single responsibility maybe more precise ... 1st/ in software development, we often try to avoid hybrid/chimera as possible. 2st/ readability /3st few third party might feel weird about  application/vnd.myapp.order.v1+json and get confused...

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems useful it would be a violation of SoC and cause additional issues down the line as your API evolves.

Versioning your URLs is the better choice here, as URL is a perfect way to signal what type of resource is being dealt with and relation to the data it handles.
*(To me introducing a custom header sounds much better design-wise then a custom versioned media type)*

Custom media types are generally supposed to tell a consumer about the type of the data and its encoding scheme (e.g. xml vs json vs plain text and so on) and not how your fields are arranged from version to version while the encoding scheme is literally unchanged.

By choosing this path you would:

1. Force consumers of your API to tightly couple to that specific “representation” that creates maintenance issues on both sides.
2. Whenever you have multiple “versions” of your API co-existing at a given time - it introduce ambiguity when bodiless https methods such as DELETE or HEAD are used as the request information would simply be insufficient to correctly route your request, let alone the backend code completely.
3. It renders rels (Link Relation Types) less usable in their normal form (if you’d ever want to introduce them)